# Highchart Change lineWidth of a Serie

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I was wondering if it is possible to change the lineWidth of a Serie in Highcharts dynamically using a external button for example. 
I have been reading all documentation, but I'm afraid this functionality is not available.

Thanks & regards!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

Using [this](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.line.lineWidth) property you can set the line width. Just make a button change the options and call `chart.redraw()`

If you want to change only one of the series, do like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-linewidth-specific/)

Comment: can we access those properties after the chart has been displayed ? the Series object has a read only option field and I can't see any editable field that match lineWidth ?

Answer (score 1):

Specify 'lineWidth'. Try this-

```
series: [{
        name: '',
      color: '#ffe8d0',
        data: [7.0, 16.9, 19.5, 24.5, 38.2, 41.5, 55.2, 66.5],
      lineWidth: 7,
    },]
```